# ElasticNet extremely slow

Tags: performance, scikit-learn

I am runnning an Elastic net model using sklearn. My dataset has 70k observations and 20 features. I want to test different parameters and use the following code:

```
alpha_plot, l1_ratio_plot = np.linspace(min_xlim, max_xlim, 50), np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
alpha_grid, l1_ratio_grid = np.meshgrid(alpha_plot, l1_ratio_plot)
l1_ratio_alpha_grid = np.array([l1_ratio_grid.ravel(), alpha_grid.ravel()]).T

model_coefficients_analysis = []

for i in l1_ratio_alpha_grid:
    
    model_analysis = ElasticNet(alpha=i[1], l1_ratio=i[0], fit_intercept=True, max_iter=10000).fit(self.features_train_std, self.labels_train)
    model_coefficients_analysis.append(model_analysis.coef_)
```

I am aware that this can be done with GridsearchCV but it doesn't do the job for me as I need to store the coefficients for every combination of parameters tested. The current code snippet is exceptionally slow. It takes roughly 10 minutes for each of the 50*10 iterations. Is there a way to speed up the process? For example in GridsearchCV there is a parameter n_jobs which can be set equal to -1 to speed up the process. But here I do not seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It takes roughly 10 minutes for each of the 50*10 iterations

That seems very high, but you also have rather large data; I can't fit a randomized such dataset in memory in Colab (where I usually run examples for answers here).  You might not be able to shrink the first fit time very much, but maybe you can reduce the subsequent fit times by using warm-starting.

Setting `warm_start=True` and using the same model object for each iteration, the coefficients will be saved as a starting point for the solver in the next iteration:

```py
model_analysis = ElasticNet(fit_intercept=True, max_iter=10000)
for i in l1_ratio_alpha_grid:
    model_analysis.set_params(alpha=i[1], l1_ratio=i[0])
    model_analysis.fit(self.features_train_std, self.labels_train)
    model_coefficients_analysis.append(model_analysis.coef_)
```

You might consider using `ElasticNetCV`, since it uses warm-starting internally, and it provides some other niceties.  You can use a `PredefinedSplit` if adding k-fold cross-validation is too much of an added expense, but I believe the `n_jobs` parameter is only useful in splitting up jobs across hyperparameters and folds, so using more cores might mitigate the issues with k-fold (but then you'll also have k times as many coefficients).

Your large `max_iter` is a bit worrying; do you get nonconvergence?  From your independent variable name it seems like you're scaling, but if not that's the place to start: fast (and maybe correct) convergence depends on features with similar scales.  You might also consider increasing the convergence criterion `tol`.  I have no experience with the `selection` parameter, but the docstring suggests changing it to `random` may speed up convergence?